# Unsuccessful post to asp.net form using Python requests

Tags: python, asp.net

I am attempting to use Python requests to post a value to the "employer" form in the http://www.myvisajobs.com/Search_Visa_Sponsor.aspx?N=

This is what I have tried so far in Python:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.myvisajobs.com/Search_Visa_Sponsor.aspx?N="
data = {"ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCompany":"Microsoft"}
r = requests.post(url,data)
print(r.text)
```

Which returns only the original HTML. I am trying to return the resulting HTML. My gut feeling is I am doing something fundamentally wrong, but I am not sure what.

Comment: I've edited the tags to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are much more parameters sent in the search POST request than just the `ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCompany` referring to the company name.

Instead, to make things transparent and easy, I would use [`RoboBrowser`](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser) that would "auto-fill" other form POST parameters needed. Example working code:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser


url = "http://www.myvisajobs.com/Search_Visa_Sponsor.aspx?N="

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open(url)

form = browser.get_form(id='aspnetForm')
form['ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCompany'].value = 'Microsoft'
browser.submit_form(form)

results = browser.select('div#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_divContent table tr')[1:]
for result in results:
    cells = result.find_all("td")

    print(cells[2].get_text(strip=True))
```

It prints the company names from the search results:

```
Microsoft Corporation
Microsoft Operations Puerto Rico, Llc
Microsoft Caribbean, Inc.
Standard Microsystems Corporation
4Microsoft Corporation
Microsoft Business Solutions Corporation
Microsoft C98052orporation
Microsoft Ccrporation
Microsoft Coiporation
Microsoft Copporation
Microsoft Corforation
Microsoft Licensing, GP
Microsoft Way
Microsoftech Inc
Quantitative Micro Software Llc
Webtv Networks Microsoft Sub
Microsoft
FAST, A Microsoft Subsidiary
Microsoft Corporation - Sham
Microsoft Partner Careers (sponsored By Microsoft Dynamics)
Microsoft Iberica
Microsoft Karthi
```

Comment: If you don't mind... What are the other parameters getting sent?

Comment: @user32882 just open browser developer tools, network tab, submit a form and inspect the POST request that would appear in the network grid. Hope that helps.