# Unable to receive desired results from POST in Python

Tags: python, pandas, post, python-requests

I am attempting to get data from [ITC TradeMap](https://www.trademap.org/Country_SelProductCountry_TS.aspx?nvpm=1%7C008%7C%7C%7C%7C88%7C%7C%7C2%7C1%7C1%7C1%7C2%7C1%7C2%7C1%7C1%7C1) (I have selected the page at random so don't give that too much thought) using Requests and then clean (have not done this yet) and export it using Pandas, however I am facing difficulties getting the full datasets.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq

#Pandas Settings
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 999)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 999)

#Request Settings
url = 'https://www.trademap.org/Country_SelProductCountry_TS.aspx?nvpm=1%7c643%7c%7c%7c%7c36%7c%7c%7c2%7c1%7c1%7c2%7c2%7c1%7c2%7c1%7c1%7c1'
headers = {
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
}
payload = {
            'ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$HiddenField_Current_OutputMode': 'T',
            'ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$HiddenField_Current_PageSizeTab': '300',
            'ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$HiddenField_Current_TS_NumTimePeriod': '10',
            'ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$HiddenField_Current_TS_ReferencePeriod': '2019'
         }

#Output Settings
output_file = 'ITC_Test.xlsx'

#Work
request = rq.post(url, verify=False, headers= headers, data=payload)

table = pd.read_html(request.content)

table[8].to_excel(output_file)

print(table[8])
```

So far I am in the testing stage of this and solving issues as they arise (e.g. If requested without `verify = False`, it throws a severside *ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)* error), but that's besides the point.

The real problem I am facing is that while most data needed for successful queries is contained in the url itself and I will simply `for` loop through it when time comes, the view settings are not, and without them I am limited to retrieving only 25 rows and 5 columns of data (top 25 trade partners over the last 5 years).

Those settings are located in dropdown windows which seem to be fed into a `aspnetForm`, I have tried to use `data` parameter of `post` to feed it with those values:

```
payload = {
            'ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$HiddenField_Current_OutputMode': 'T',
            'ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$HiddenField_Current_PageSizeTab': '300',
            'ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$HiddenField_Current_TS_NumTimePeriod': '10',
            'ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$HiddenField_Current_TS_ReferencePeriod': '2019'
         }
```

However the output does not seem to be affected and it still only returns 25 rows and 5 columns of data instead of 300 rows and 10 columns I would expect it to.

Thanks!

I have seen some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758600/unsuccessful-post-to-asp-net-form-using-python-requests) here which seemed similar and tries to implement those ideas, however most likely due to the fact that I haven't worked with those libraries and my knowledge of Python in general is rather basic I was unable to resolve the issues so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: server may send different values in every request so you should first GET page and get values from `aspnetForm` and later use it in POST - so script has to behave like real human. And post may send new `aspnetForm` values which you should use to POST next data, etc.

Comment: Usually in POST you have to send ALL values which browser sends to server - you can't send only 4 values  because server may check all of them and compare settings with `_VIEWSTATE`

Comment: you selected random url which always give 25 results - even in browser - so it is useless in question, and I only wasted time for it. You should add URL which really may have more results.

Comment: but main problem is that this page uses JavaScript to generate some values and may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I found 3 problems:

1. it has to use `Session()` to send cookies
2. it has to send all values in payload - so first I GET page to get all values from `<input>`, `<select>`
3. it sends new values in different variables.

You used variables which described current state but it send in variables with `DropDownList` in name

```
payload['ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$DropDownList_NumTimePeriod'] = '20'
payload['ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$DropDownList_PageSize'] = '300'
```

**EDIT:**

I saved payload generated by code and payload from browser and I used program [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) to compare files to see differences.

I had to correct code which gets values from `<select>` because it needs to search `<option>` with `selected`

For some addresses it needed to manually some values because normally JavaScript was adding these values

And it needed to skip `DropDownList_Product_Group`

---

Full working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

# hide SSL warnings
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
rq.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

# request settings

#url = 'https://www.trademap.org/Country_SelProduct_TS.aspx?nvpm=1%7c%7c%7c%7c%7c88%7c%7c%7c2%7c1%7c1%7c1%7c2%7c1%7c2%7c1%7c1%7c1'
url = 'https://www.trademap.org/Country_SelProductCountry_TS.aspx?nvpm=1%7c616%7c%7c%7c%7cTOTAL%7c%7c%7c2%7c1%7c1%7c1%7c2%7c1%7c2%7c1%7c%7c1'

print('url:', url.replace('%7c', '|'))

headers = {
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
}

s = rq.Session()

# --- GET ---

print('sending GET ...')

response = s.get(url, verify=False, headers=headers)
    
soup = BS(response.content, 'html.parser')
form = soup.find('form') #.find('div', {'id': 'div_nav_combo'})

payload = {}

#print('--- inputs ---')        
inputs = form.find_all('input')
for item in inputs:# + select:
    name = item.get('name', '')
    #print('name:', name)
    value = item.get('value', '')
    #print('value:', value)

    if name: #and name != 'pg_goal' and 'button' not in name.lower():
        payload[name] = value
        #print(name, '=', value)
    
#print('--- selects ---')        
selects = form.find_all('select')
for item in selects:
    name = item.get('name', '')
    #print('name:', name)
    value = item.get('value', '')
    #print('value:', value)

    if name:
        value = item.find('option', {'selected': True}) or ""
        if value:
            value = value['value']
        payload[name] = value
        #print(name, '=', value)

#print('--- textareas ---')        
#textareas = form.find_all('textarea')
#for item in textareas:
#    name = item.get('name', '')
#    print('name:', name)
#    value = item.get('value', '')
#    print('value:', value)

# --- POST ---

print('sending POST ...')

#payload['ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$DropDownList_NumTimePeriod'] = '20'
#payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$DropDownList_NumTimePeriod'

payload['ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$DropDownList_PageSize'] = '300'
#payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$DropDownList_PageSize'

#payload['ctl00$MenuControl$DDL_Language'] = 'en'

# added by JavaScript
payload['ctl00$NavigationControl$DropDownList_Country_Group'] = '-2'
payload['ctl00$NavigationControl$DropDownList_Partner'] = '-2'
payload['ctl00$NavigationControl$DropDownList_Partner_Group'] = '-2'

# has to remove it for `PageSize` (at least for some addresses)
del payload['ctl00$NavigationControl$DropDownList_Product_Group']
        
response = s.post(url, verify=False, headers=headers, data=payload)

#print(response.content[:1000])

# --- rest ---

# pandas settings
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 999)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 999)

# output settings
output_file = 'ITC_Test.xlsx'

all_tables = pd.read_html(response.content)

table = all_tables[8]

table.to_excel(output_file)

print('len(table):', len(table))
#print(table)
```

Result: table with ~230 rows and ~20 columns

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help, and sorry about the url when testing I was mostly paying attention to the number of columns and not rows. If you have a bit more time i would very much appreciate if you could help me resolve another issue that popped up.
/part (1 of 3)

Comment: When using your code for extracting trade between all countries (e.g. https://www.trademap.org/Country_SelProduct_TS.aspx?nvpm…) it seems to work as intended, however when applying it to trade of individual ones (https://www.trademap.org/Country_SelProduct**Country**_TS.aspx?nvpm…) the column payload works as intended, but the row payload does not.
/part (2 of 3)

Comment: I have looked through the parameters being passed along and aside from obvious difference that `ctl00$NavigationControl$HiddenField_Current_CountryCode` gets a value assigned to it, that such things as `ctl00$forgeryToken` change and that the all the `ctl00$PageContent$MyGridView1$ctl04$breakDown`(ctl04 to ctl27) change from breakDown to bilateral, there don’t appear to be any differences.

I have tried also modifying the `Current` and `Prev` iterations of the value along with `DropDownList`, but it did not help either. Any idea for why it may be doing this? Thanks!

Comment: maybe different pages use different values - and they need different code.

Comment: You mean the whole code in general or one of the parameters? Because if I understood your code correctly it checks the url for all options and fetches them regardless, and even then aside from the changes I mentioned in the third comment, the parameter names stayed the same with the same options. Thanks either way, I will try to look into it in the morning.

Comment: I found problem(s). (1) I don't get values from `<select>` - I have to get `<option>` and search `selected`, (2) page uses JavaScript to set some values in `<select>` and it needs to set it manually in `payload` (3) I get all `<input>` but some of them has to be skiped for `SelProductCountry` - it is `ctl00$NavigationControl$DropDownList_Product_Group`. After that I ge ~229 for `SelProductCountry`. Later I put code - I have to clean it.

Comment: I added new code